# Mysqli results loop in case if same group multiple results

Tags: php, mysqli

I am building a calendar with events, now while generating days of weeks the script connects to the database and takes event information from there.

It suppose to display events to each day that has event in database, that works fine, BUT once you have multiple events at the same day, it shows just one of the events to that day.

If i just echo the $cellContent than it shows all of the events.
If i use return $cellContent ( for further days generation and placement to html calendar ) it will show only 1 of the events for each day that has event.

For example there are 5 events, "A" event at 22th of the month, "B" at 24th, "C" at 28th, "D" at 28th too, "E" at 28th too, the script will show only A B C events.

Any suggestions? With examples please

```
public function show() {
      $year = null;
      $month = null;
      $year = date("Y", time());
      $month = date("m", time());

      $this->currentYear = $year;
      $this->currentMonth = $month;
      $this->daysInMonth = $this->_daysInMonth($month, $year);
      $content = '<div id="calendar">' . "\r\n" . '<div class="calendar_box">' . "\r\n" . $this->_createNavi() . "\r\n" . '</div>' . "\r\n" . '<div class="calendar_content">' . "\r\n" . '<ul class="calendar_label">' . "\r\n" . $this->_createLabels() . '</ul>' . "\r\n";
      $content .= '<div class="calendar_clear"></div>' . "\r\n";
      $content .= '<ul class="calendar_dates">' . "\r\n";
      $weeksInMonth = $this->_weeksInMonth($month, $year);
      // Create weeks in a month
      for ($i = 0; $i < $weeksInMonth; $i++) {
        //Create days in a week
        for ($j = 1; $j <= 7; $j++) {
          $content .= $this->_showDay($i * 7 + $j);
        }
      }
      $content .= '</ul>' . "\r\n";
      $content .= '<div class="calendar_clear"></div>' . "\r\n";
      $content .= '</div>' . "\r\n";
      $content .= '</div>' . "\r\n";
      return $content;
    }
private function _showDay($cellNumber) {
      if ($this->currentDay == 0) {
        $firstDayOfTheWeek = date('N', strtotime($this->currentYear . '-' . $this->currentMonth . '-01'));
        if (intval($cellNumber) == intval($firstDayOfTheWeek)) {
          $this->currentDay = 1;
        }
      }
      if (($this->currentDay != 0) && ($this->currentDay <= $this->daysInMonth)) {
        $this->currentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->currentYear . '-' . $this->currentMonth . '-' . ($this->currentDay)));
        $cellContent = $this->currentDay;
        $this->currentDay++;
      } else {
        $this->currentDate = null;
        $cellContent = null;
      }
      $today_day = date("d");
      $today_mon = date("m");
      $today_yea = date("Y");
      $class_day = ($cellContent == $today_day && $this->currentMonth == $today_mon && $this->currentYear == $today_yea ? "calendar_today" : "calendar_days");

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $dbname = "test";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT owner, title, opening FROM _sites
            WHERE YEAR(opening) = $today_yea AND MONTH(opening) = $today_mon";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             $dfd = $row['opening'];
             $dfd = explode("-", $dfd );
                    if ($cellContent == $dfd[2] && $this->currentMonth == $dfd[1] && $this->currentYear == $dfd[0]){
                        $class_day = "calendar_event";
                        $cellContent = '<a href="#">' . $cellContent . '</a><div>';
                        $cellContent = $cellContent .'<a href="' . $row['owner'] . '">' . $row['title'] . '</a><br>' . $row['opening'] . '<hr>';
                        $cellContent = $cellContent . '</div>';
                    }
         }
    } else {
         echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();

      return '<li class="' . $class_day . '">' . $cellContent . '</li>' . "\r\n";
    }
```

Comment: you're doing `$cellcontent = `, so if you get multiple records back, you'll just replace previous records with the new/current one.

Comment: No the other part of the script uses this foreach return.

Ught i will just post normal piece of the script , moment

Comment: You check if `$cellContent` is the day of the event and then update `$cellContent` by wrapping a `<li>` around it; it won't match the 2nd record for that day then. Use something like `if ( $this->currentDay == $dfd[2] && ... ) { $cellContent .= ... }`

Comment: Updated the post now you can see both functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your functions much simpler. First of all, modify your `for` loops to use days instead of weeks, and improve your DB connection logic:

```
// No need to connect to DB every time you call the _showDay().
// Just do it once (create a private variable $this->conn).
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$this->conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $this->conn->connect_error);
}

// $weeksInMonth = $this->_weeksInMonth($month, $year);
// Remove the line above and add this instead:
$daysInMonth = date("t");
for ($i = 1; $i <= $daysInMonth; $i++) {
    $content .= $this->_showDay($i);
}
// And the rest of your code...
$content .= '</ul>' . "\r\n";
```

Then, you modify your `_showDay()` function, removing the unnecessary checks:

```
private function _showDay($day) {
    $today_day = date("d");
    $class_day = ($day == $today_day ? "calendar_today" : "calendar_days");

    // Build a date in YYYY-MM-DD format and pass it over into SQL
    $currentDate = $this->currentYear .'-'. $this->currentMonth .'-'. str_pad($day, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $sql = "SELECT owner, title, opening FROM _sites
            WHERE DATE(opening) = '". $currentDate ."'";
    $result = $this->conn->query($sql);

    // No need to do anything else if nothing is happening on this day.
    if (empty($result->num_rows)) {
        $conn->close();
        return '<li class="' . $class_day . '">0 results</li>' . "\r\n";
    }

    // Otherwise, build the content.
    // Let's not clutter the code with endless concatenation and
    // use output buffering and echo statements instead.
    ob_start();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<a href="#">' . $day . '</a><div>';
        echo '<a href="' . $row['owner'] . '">' . $row['title'] . '</a><br>' . $row['opening'] . '<hr>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    $conn->close();
    return '<li class="calendar_event">' . ob_get_clean() . '</li>' . "\r\n";
}
```

The whole logic can (and should) be optimized more - for example, using only one SQL query returning all events at once, grouped by date, and pass the results into `_showDay()`, but I think this should do for now.

Comment: Thanks, now having other prob, on many events at the same date it generates the date day multiple times

Comment: I've modified my answer slightly to optimize your DB connection logic. Make sure your SELECT returns something inside `_showDay()`. Try echo'ing the $sql to see if it gives you a valid query.

Comment: Edited, moved the div and day tags outside of the while tag. Now everything is PERFECT!

Comment: what if i want to select WHERE date(opening) or date(closing) ? and show closing dates too while generating just in different colors

Comment: Just add this OR to your WHERE. As for colors, you can check if the $currentDate is equal either to your $row['opening'] or $row['closing'], and add CSS classes depending on it.